Вывести список врачей в виде кнопок в телеграм боте
Пытаюсь реализовать следующее: есть команда /doctors, которая выводит специальности врачей в виде кнопок, затем когда пользователь нажимает на специальность нужно вывести врачей этой специальности в виде кнопок. И на конец когда пользователь нажмет на врача вывести расписание его. Сам код выглядит так:
import logging
import oracledb
import base64
import json
from datetime import datetime
import telebot
from telebot import types

with open('config.json', 'r') as config_file:
    config = json.load(config_file)

token = config['telegram_bot_token']
db_user = config['db_user']
db_password = config['db_password']
db_dsn = config['db_dsn']
connection = oracledb.connect(user=db_user, password=db_password, dsn=db_dsn)

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

pool = oracledb.create_pool(user=db_user, password=db_password, dsn=db_dsn, min=2, max=10, increment=1)

def send_long_message(chat_id, text, chunk_size=4096):
    for i in range(0, len(text), chunk_size):
        bot.send_message(chat_id, text[i:i + chunk_size])

# Обработчик команды /doctors
@bot.message_handler(commands=['doctors'])
def show_specialties(message):
    try:
        with pool.acquire() as connection:
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute("select distinct l1.text from docdep dd, lu l1, lu l2 where dd.status = 1 and dd.depid in (18,36,37,38,39,41) and dd.specid = l1.keyid and dd.positionid = l2.keyid and lower(l2.text) like '%врач%' order by l1.text")
                results = cursor.fetchall()
                if results:
                    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
                    for row in results:
                        specialty = row[0]
                        markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=specialty, callback_data=f'spec_{specialty}'))
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Выберите специальность:", reply_markup=markup)
                else:
                    bot.reply_to(message, "Специальности не найдены.")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error occurred: {e}")
        bot.reply_to(message, "Произошла ошибка при обработке вашего запроса.")

# Функция для вывода списка врачей выбранной специальности в виде кнопок
def show_doctors_by_specialty(call, specialty):
    print(specialty)
    try:
        with pool.acquire() as connection:
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute("""
                    select dd.text
                    from docdep dd, lu l1, lu l2
                    where dd.status = 1
                    and dd.depid in (18, 36, 37, 38, 39, 41)
                    and dd.specid = l1.keyid
                    and dd.positionid = l2.keyid
                    and lower(l2.text) like '%врач%'
                    and l1.text = :specialty""", specialty=specialty)
                results = cursor.fetchall()
                if results:
                    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
                    for row in results:
                        doctor_name = row[0]
                        print(f'doc_{specialty}_{doctor_name}')
                        markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=doctor_name, callback_data=f'doc_{specialty}_{doctor_name}'))
                    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, f"Выберите врача по специальности '{specialty}':", reply_markup=markup)
                else:
                    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, f"Врачи по специальности '{specialty}' не найдены.")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error occurred: {e}")
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Произошла ошибка при обработке вашего запроса.")

# Функция для вывода расписания выбранного врача
def show_schedule(call, specialty, doctor_name):
    try:
        with pool.acquire() as connection:
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute("""
                    select
                    (select min(r.dat) from rnumb where rdayid=r.rdayid) as date1,
                    (select max(r.dat1) from rnumb where rdayid=r.rdayid) as date2,
                    l.text as potok
                    from rnumb r, lu l 
                    where r.docdepid in (select keyid from docdep dd where dd.text like '%' || :doctor_name || '%')
                    and trunc(r.dat) between sysdate-1 and (sysdate+5) 
                    and nvl(r.patientid,0)=0 
                    and r.dirid = l.keyid
                    """, doctor_name=doctor_name)
                results = cursor.fetchall()
                if results:
                    response = f"Расписание для врача '{doctor_name}' по специальности '{specialty}':\n\n"
                    for result in results:
                        date1 = result[0].strftime("%d:%m:%Y %H:%M") if result[0] else "N/A"
                        date2 = result[1].strftime("%d:%m:%Y %H:%M") if result[1] else "N/A"
                        potok = result[2] if result[2] else "N/A"
                        response += f"С {date1} по {date2}, поток: {potok}\n\n"
                    send_long_message(call.message.chat.id, response)
                else:
                    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, f"Расписание для врача '{doctor_name}' по специальности '{specialty}' не найдено.")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error occurred: {e}")
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Произошла ошибка при обработке вашего запроса.")

# Обработчик нажатий кнопок специальностей
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data.startswith('spec_'))
def handle_specialty_callback(call):
    specialty = call.data.split('_')[1]  # Получаем выбранную специальность из callback_data
    print(specialty)
    show_doctors_by_specialty(call, specialty)

# Обработчик нажатий кнопок врачей
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data.startswith('doc_'))
def handle_doctor_callback(call):
    data_parts = call.data.split('_')
    specialty = data_parts[1]
    doctor_name = data_parts[2]
    show_schedule(call, specialty, doctor_name)

# Обработчик команды /start или /help для начала работы бота
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def handle_start(message):
    show_specialties(message)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)

Специальности выводятся в виде кнопок, но если нажму на какую-то специальность, выходит ошибка в консоли:

ERROR:root:Error occurred: A request to the Telegram API was
unsuccessful. Error  code: 400. Description: Bad Request:
BUTTON_DATA_INVALID


Кажется это связано с тем что в передаваемых специальностях есть пробелы., но как с этим справиться не знаю.

В принципе разобрался, вместо doctor_name передал id доктора.

Покажите нам, как выглядит список врачей, дополните вопрос.

Все идут гуськом друг за другом по одним и тем же граблям. Тоже делаю раписание вы тупо упретесь в возможности этой библиотеки посмотрите лучше любую из этих двух они сложнее не на много:
https://www.libhunt.com/compare-python-telegram-bot-vs-aiogram

Скажите пожалуйста, почему эти библиотека лучше и с чем можно столкнуться? Я пока что реализовал вывод расписания в текстовом виде, вроде работает.

Это библиотека начального уровня. Она позволяет быстро получить результат. Но строительные блоки большие, строя из больших блоков можно построить быстро на плата за это потеря гибкости.  Если на пальцах это как лего и лего дупло. Очень скоро вы захотите сделать где то в стене оконце и вам прийдется переносить все решение на более мелкие кубики это тупо двойная работа. Проще говоря если ваша задача проста и примитивна и не вырастет во что то более сложное то возможно вам и хавтит крупноблочной библиотеки. Но чаще всего это не так. Аппетит приходит во время еды.

Вот вам первый минус, ваш бот синхронный. Расписание врачей выкладывают в строго определенное время. И в это же время одновременно десятки людей будут пытатся получить доступ к одним и темже данным. В отличие допустим от какого нибудь опроса., где нагрузка более размазана. Это с архитектурной точки зрения потенциально узкое место.

Спасибо , буду иметь ввиду. Пока бот не сильно функционален, он лишь получает из БД расписание, выводит его и пару других функций типа получить историю лечения, результаты исследований.. Думаю сильно не будет расти функциональность, но на будущее учту ваши советы.
